# How to validate some fields and selects on ng-click AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I have a list of some input fields and few select options, so I want them be required on ng-click and raise a message just over the particular required item in form of PopupMenu or kind of that, or **what ever the suitable way to show require warning just over the field**

Hierarchy in my case:

```
<form>
   <input required
   <input required

   location form for multiple records (not form tag)

   contact form for multiple contacts (not form tag)

   submit button to post (input required), all locations and all contacts.
</form>
```

My Form:

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Legal Name" ng-model="companyForm.legalName" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" placeholder="EIN" ng-model="companyForm.ein"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="selectFormationDiv">
        <select id="formationListId"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" style="margin-top: 5px;" ng-model="companyForm.internal"/> <b>Internal</b>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note** this is not form, and not be called on ng-submit.

My Output:
[image]

My Desired output:
[image]

> Please guide me through how do I code to get my desired output. Thanks

Comment: You can validate form inputs using this links - [FormBuilder](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder).

Answer (score 1):

```js
angular.module('app', [])
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app'>
  <form name="form" class="css-form" novalidate>
    <input type='text' ng-model='temp1' required name='temp1' />
    <span ng-show="form.temp1.$error.required && form.$submitted" class='error'>
      field1 is required
    </span>
    <br>
    <input type='text' ng-model='temp2' required name='temp2' />
    <span ng-show="form.temp2.$error.required && form.$submitted" class='error'>
      field2 is required
    </span>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
  </form>
  <hr>

  <!--Solution without `<form>` tag: -->
  <input type='text' ng-model='temp3' name='temp3' />
  <span ng-show="!temp3 && $submitted" class='error'>field3 is required</span>
  <br>
  <input type='text' ng-model='temp4' name='temp4' />
  <span ng-show="!temp4 && $submitted" class='error'>field4 is required</span>
  <br>
  <input type="button" ng-click='$submitted=true' value="Save" />
</div>
```

Comment: it's great. Hope to try it later. But I mentioned that I'm not using <form> tag. So how could we get the same output without using form tag. Thanks. Waiting for your response.

Comment: You don't use `<form>`, because don't want to post it to server? At this case , it will not happen, so `<form>` is just technological(helping) tag.

Comment: Please understand the hirarchy, in my case:
form tag starts

   few info fields..some required (your answer works fine)

   location: Add multiple locations (but this location form is not actually using form tag, there simple input fields and one button to keep adding multiple records)

   contact: Add multiple contacts

form tag ends...

Comment: @BadshahTracker, ok, try second variant without `<form>`